# Zepto JS is making the scrolling in my phonegap app unresponsive

Tags: jquery, cordova, zepto

Anyone else had this before?

Scrolling works... but if you scroll too quickly the page just stays still. You need to do it kind of slowly.

I know it's zepto, too, as if I make a new page with *just* the zepto library imported (not even calling anything from it), it behaves this way.
Remove it and the scrolling works perfectly again!

What gives... I thought zepto was supposed to just be a minimalistic jQuery-like library... but even the full jQuery library doesn't hinder my scrolling like this!

---

SOLVED, for me anyway.

Check the comments below.

Comment: Could you please provide a demo case and a fiddle?

Comment: Would a fiddle help? It's on Android where the scrolling becomes unresponsive, not on a computer.

All I've got a test page which is just a basic HTML page with zepto and cordova imported. In the body is a UL with about 200 LIs. That's it.

Build to Android, scrolling unresponsive. Switch zepto with jQuery, scrolling responsive :-/

Comment: Oh... that's curious.

I built a version of Zepto *without* the touch events module and suddenly everything seems to be responsive. Hmmmmmmmm!

Comment: I have also encountered this and was wondering what it was. I might try without touch.js as well and see if it's the culprit. I am assuming you are using css scrolling not a js scrolling lib linke iScroll?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I figured out the issue - it's line 56 of zepto's touch.js module - 

.bind('touchmove')... etc

basically, the if statement within the bind will completely disable any kind of interaction if the touch and release time was too small (i guess trying to negate accidental touches). However this really screws with scrolling, especially if you use quick flicks.

I just commented out the if statement (line 60) and everything's fine again. I'll deal with proper touch handling later.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed happening on Android with Zepto Touch. Was pulling my hair out for hours on a PhoneGap app before stumbling here and finding it is Zepto that is the problem. (I had no problem on iOS after adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`)

This was my workaround:

```
$('.scrolling').bind('touchmove', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); }
```

This prevented Zepto's check for accidental touches from happening on certain divs that have scrolling enabled (in this case, with a manual 'scrolling' class) for me, but YMMV.